# Inverting a Linear Fractional Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, mobius-transformation

I have a particular Linear Fractional Transformation from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, I am using to solve Laplace's equation, and I was hoping to find the inverse of this transformation.  Is there a algorithm that can be used to find the inverse of a Linear Fractional Transformation?  Are there any useful algorithms for special cases?

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of the linear fractional transformation 
$$z\to \frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$$ is the linear fractional transformation
$$z\to \frac{e z + f}{g z + h}$$ where the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}e & f\\ g & h\end{pmatrix}$$ is the inverse of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: don't even need to divide through by determinant...